# How to create an aggregating REST service?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, restful-architecture

In my company we have several basic REST services consumed by our web and mobile applications. (Please read REST as only JSON over HTTP with only POST calls).

In order to improve the performance of the mobile client (network overhead of many http calls) we would like to be able to aggregate some REST calls. 
We would like to find a generic solution so the mobile client is free to choice which services to aggregate.

The solution currently found is a generic REST service that receives the json with the list of requests and delegates 
to a pool of threads the execution of each request. When all requests are completed the service collects all the 
responses in a list and return it as aggregated response.

This solution has some problems:

1. The spring or javax validation is not applied (is invoked in the aggregating service)
2. Session scoped data is not available in servant thread (a workaround found via ThreadLocal)
3. Filters and Interceptors are not applied on the single request (no solution yet)
4. Potentially others issues yet undiscovered

Does spring(mvc) offer a better way to do the same?

Can **HandlerInterceptor** help me in re-implement the same logic in a safer way?

Thanks
Vito

Comment: Would an ESB (Enterprise Service Bus) be of use?  In my previous job we used WSo2 to aggregate and transform SOAP XML payloads.  Not sure if it can handle JSON, though.